# Codeigniter Ajax insert values in a select box based on other select value

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have two `select` boxes. First one's value is like below.

[image: Select Boxes]

My `MySQL` table is like below.

[image: MySQL Table]

If anybody selects `General Stream` from first `select` box, the second `select` box options will be like...

```
<option value="1">Honours</option>
<option value="2">General</option>
```

But if anyone selects `Vocational` from first `select` box, the second `select` box option will be like...

```
<option value="2">General</option>
```

---

In my `controller` have done this...

```
function get_coursetype()
{
    $r=$this->input->post("coursetype");
    $_SESSION['coursetype']=$r;
    //print json_encode($_SESSION['coursetype']);
    if($r=='Honours'){
        $qry = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM course');
        $data = array_shift($qry->result_array());
        echo json_encode($data['curs']);
    } else {
        $qry = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM course WHERE curs="General"');
        $data = array_shift($qry->result_array());
        echo json_encode($data['curs']);
    }
}
```

And in ajax, I have done this...

```
$(function(){ // start of doc ready.
   $("#CourseType").change(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();  // stops the jump when an anchor clicked.
   var coursetype = $(this).val(); // anchors do have text not values.

  $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?/admission/get_coursetype',
    data: {'coursetype': coursetype}, // change this to send js object
    type: "post",
    success: function(data){

        loc = data;
        $('#course').empty();
        $('#course').show();
        $.each(loc,function(data){
            $('#course').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",data).text(data));
        });
    }
  });
   });
});
```

It is showing error...
[image: error_msg]

How could I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

even tough the whole scenario is a mess, i don't understand what you want to achieve with array_shift - try this instead

```
function get_coursetype()
{
    $r=$this->input->post("coursetype");
    $_SESSION['coursetype']=$r;
    //print json_encode($_SESSION['coursetype']);
    if($r=='1'){
        $qry = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM course');
        $data = $qry->result_array();
    } else {
        $qry = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM course WHERE curs="General"');
        $data = $qry->result_array();
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

and in your ajax query just use your mysql keys in your each loop

```
$(function()
{ // start of doc ready.
    $("#CourseType").change(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();  // stops the jump when an anchor clicked.
        var coursetype = $(this).val(); // anchors do have text not values.

        $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'index.php?/admission/get_coursetype',
            data: {'coursetype': coursetype}, // change this to send js object
            type: "post",
            success: function(data)
            {
                loc = data;
                $('#course').empty();
                $('#course').show();
                $.each(loc,function(data){
                    $('#course').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",data.id).text(data.curs));
                });
            }
        });
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I, mistakenly, used `array_shift`. However I changed my code and I got my desired result. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: And this `mess` I created to explain my problem. Sorry for It.

Comment: hehe np, what i meant with "mess" is, you shoud leave your data handlings in your models - queries in your controller set aside the purpose of a model, and for the clientside you might think about backbone and handlebars or such thing ;)